# Inserting into specific vector index using i (for loop)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, c++17

How would I insert values into a specific vector element using **i** (for loop)

If the vector is 100,000 in size thread 1 needs to insert from 0 to 49,999 as another thread will do 50,000 - 99,999.

The vector cannot **push_back** and **must insert**, as it is important to insert at a specific index **i**.

This is needed because, thread 1 will push back onto element 0, and then concurrently thread 2 will push back onto element 1. This will completely ruin the indexing of where thread 2 is supposed to index from. (50,000 - 99,999)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should define your `std::vector` with the initial size, here 100000.

Example:

```
std::vecor<int> data(100000,0);
```

This can be done with [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) number 3 or 4. For your case it is nearly a must to avoid reallocation and many copy activities.

And then you can simply use the [index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) operator `[]`in your threads to assign values to the vectors elements.

Comment: Hi, yeah initially I had myVector[i] = var; but I just noticed that I am trying to allocate a variable into a vector element that does not exist. Ah, how push_back makes everything simple with its automatic vector resize. Just defined the vector size and allocated with i.

Comment: Note that that initializes every element in the vector with a copy of the argument, `0` in this case. If that is costly, copying the element is not allowed or there is no good default value to use then you can use `std::optional` and initialize everything to `std::nullopt_t` (default, so you don't have to anything). The threads then update the optional to the result when they finished computing.